# Protractor test not recognizing global variable defined in onPrepare method within protractor.conf.js

Tags: protractor, global-variables, global, e2e-testing

I have defined a global variable within my protractor.conf.js file like this:

```
onPrepare() {
    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
}
```

I am attempting to access this variable within my protractor test like this:

```
navigateTo(url: string): LoginPage {
    browser.get(url);    
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(url), 2000);
    return this;
}
```

However, my spec is not recognizing EC. The output log as well as the VS Code intellisense says

> Cannot find name EC.

Comment: VSCode did the syntax checking.  Should pass when you run your test.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked if there are differences in the way globals are exposed through protractor's config, but the way I use it and it works well in our test suite is like this

```
 onPrepare: () => {
  EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = browser.params['timeout'];
  if (!DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) {
    DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 60000;
  }

  chai = require('chai');
  chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
  chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  expect = chai.expect;
  ...
}
```

So I don't use the "global" but expose directly and use it like this for example:

```
openCreateDialog() {
  let createButton = $('.create-new');
  browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(createButton), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
  createButton.click();
  let dialog = new NewDialog();
  dialog.waitUntilOpened();
  return dialog.getCreatePanel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't use the global and exposed it directly as you mentioned. However, it didn't work. Seems there is a problem somewhere.